# Plotly.express density_heatmap radius values based on z value

Tags: python, plotly-python

I'm working with `plotly.express` and the `density_mapbox` function. Here's my code:

```
fig = px.density_mapbox(calc_data, lat='latitude', lon='longitude', size='calc_dis_m', radius=10, mapbox_style="stamen_terrain")
fig.show()
```

It plots fine, but what I'm wondering is that if it's possible to make it so that the dots radii are based on the `calc_dis_m` values in my dataframe. That way, the dots will have radii equal to their value, so that the smaller `calc_dis_m` values are smaller on the map and the bigger values are bigger.

Is this possible within the `density_mapbox` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can assign different radius for each point by assigning a list of numbers between [1, inf]. For instance, in the code below, I assign a list of numbers between 1 and 10:

```
radius=df.Magnitude.tolist()
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/earthquakes-23k.csv')

df['Magnitude'] = np.random.rand(len(df))*10 + 1 # change the default value 

fig = px.density_mapbox(df, lat='Latitude', lon='Longitude', z='Magnitude', radius=df.Magnitude.tolist(),
                        center=dict(lat=0, lon=180), zoom=0,
                        mapbox_style="stamen-terrain")
fig.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Notes:**

*As you see in the map above, each point has different size based on the radius.*